# How to feed a vector of column names to the table function

Tags: r, dataframe

Example data:

```
mtcars <- mtcars
cols <- c("cyl", "vs")

# I would like to create a table for each column in `columns`:

for (i in seq(cols)) {
  print(table(mtcars$cols[i]))
}

# I also tried:
for (i in seq(cols)) {
  print(table(get(paste0("mtcars$", cols[i]))))
}
```

But this does not produce any table. How can I feed a vector of column names to the table function?

Comment: 1) The first instruction does nothing; 2) `for(i in columns)`, as it is defined earlier in the code, not `seq(cols)`; 3) in the loop try `print(table(mtcars[[i]]))`. Since `i` takes each of the values in `columns` there's no need to subset `columns` again.

Comment: @RuiBarradas please post as answer explaining why the forloop didn't work. `lapply` is a better solution, but it doesn't address the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
> lapply(mtcars[cols], table)
$cyl

 4  6  8
11  7 14

$vs

 0  1
18 14
```

or using `mget`

```
> with(mtcars, lapply(mget(cols), table))
$cyl

 4  6  8
11  7 14

$vs

 0  1
18 14

> lapply(mget(columns, as.environment(mtcars)), table)
$cyl

 4  6  8
11  7 14

$vs

 0  1
18 14
```

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question is not working because:

1. What is defined earlier in the code is a vector `columns`, not `cols`;
2. the loop index `i` will take each of the values in `columns`, therefore index the data set `mtcars` with it directly, `mtcars[[i]]` extracts the appropriate column. See also [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a vector of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names)

In the code below I first create a results list with the same length as `columns` and with its values as names. Then, in the `for` loop, assign the tables to the list's members.

The two commented-out instructions do what the next one-liner does.

```r
columns <- c("cyl", "vs")

# tbl_list <- vector("list", length = length(columns))
# names(tbl_list) <- columns
tbl_list <- setNames(vector("list", length = length(columns)), columns)
for (i in columns) {
  tbl_list[[i]] <- table(mtcars[[i]])
}

tbl_list
#> $cyl
#> 
#>  4  6  8 
#> 11  7 14 
#> 
#> $vs
#> 
#>  0  1 
#> 18 14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>